# Do I need to unsubscribe from an Observable if the Observable is finished with?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, rxjs

Let us say I have an `Observable` (hot, doesn't complete), and I subscribe to it. Ordinarily when I am finished with the `Subscription` I have to unsubscribe it to prevent memory leaks.

```
let subject$ = new Subject();

const sub = subject$.subscribe(...);
...
// Need to call sub.unsubscribe() when we are finished
sub.unsubscribe();
sub = null;
```

But if instead of just being finished with the `Subscription` I am also finished with the `Observable` (`Subject`) and I remove all reference to both, do I need to call `unsubscribe` method?

```
let subject$ = new Subject();

const sub = subject$.subscribe(...);
...
sub = null;
subject$=null;
// Assume I have no other references to these
// Do I need to call sub.unsubscribe() in this case?
```

My logic is telling my I don't because both the `Subject` and the `Subscription` are now eligible for garbage collection, and will be destroyed, even though they reference each other. Or is there some hidden reference I don't know about?

Don't worry about the difference between using `unsubscribe`, `takeUntil` or other mechanisms.

Comment: Hello,

Interesting question you have raised. From my experience, it is always recommended to unsubscribe but since you set `subject$=null`, this will ensure that no other emissions will be given thereby stopping the memory leak of the callback function of the subscribe being called again. By the way, to finish a subject, it has a complete method (`subject$.complete()`). For you, since `subject$` is local to you and then you set it to null, it won't be an issue. But if the observable comes from an external source, say a redux store, then it can be an issue and I would unsubscribe.

Comment: Another thing is, how to unsubscribe. There are many ways to unsubscribe but I have found using the `async` pipe (if using Angular) and `takeUntil` operators to be the most clean.

Comment: If you could make that an answer, preferably with some references to back it up, that would be great. (Don't worry about the "how to unsubscribe" part).

Comment: If there are "no other references" to the subject and the subscription, then no, you don't have to unsubscribe to effect their garbage collection. Unsubscription would only be necessary if there was a reference to either of these that was kept someplace in RxJS and that is not the case - unless you are using some debugging instrumentation like `rxjs-spy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of a `let subject$ = new Subject();` clearing the references to the `Subject` and the `Subscription` will be enough, everything will be garbage collected after that.

The risk of a memory leak gets real when you are subscribing to the `Subject` in an object, and you don't unsubscribe from the `Subject` before clearing all the references on the object. In that case, the whole object will remain active and won't be garbage collectable.

Let's take this example:

```
class BigClass {
    constructor(observable) {
        this.bigArray = new Array(9999999).fill(0);
        observable.subscribe(x => this.result = x);
    }
    //...
}

let subject = new rxjs.Subject();
let bigObject = new BigClass(subject);
let bigObject1 = new BigClass(subject);
let bigObject2 = new BigClass(subject);
let bigObject3 = new BigClass(subject);

bigObject = null;
bigObject1 = null;
bigObject2 = null;
bigObject3 = null;
```

In this example, when clearing all the references on `bigObject`, the `subject` still has a reference on the `x => this.result = x` callback which has a reference on `bigObject`, making it uncollectable as a whole.

Either by unsubscribing, or clearing the `subject`, this will break the references chain that keeps `bigObject` alive, and it will be eligible for garbage collection.

To observe the behavior by yourself, you can copy the content of this file https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js in your console, then copy paste the example code. You will notice a memory increase in the task manager. When creating a heap dump in the Memory tab in the developer tools, you'll be able to find the 4 objects by typing `BigClass` in the search field.

After that, type `subject = null;` in the console, then create a new heap dump. You'll notice that the 4 objects have disappeared.

As a conclusion, as long as an `Observable` is destroyed, these is no real risk of a memory leak because all of the subscriptions will also be destroyed. The risky `Observables` are those who are permanent (e.g: attached to a global DOM event with `fromEvent`), and with callbacks referring to objects that need to be destroyed.

Comment: It's not that I don't believe you, but do you have a reference? Also can I check that in your example the memory would be freed by setting subject=null?

Comment: I've added details on how to test and observe this on your side

Comment: hum what if you also do subject = null ?

Comment: @Ced sorry I don't get what you mean

Answer (score 0):

###### No, you don't need to

For memory usage there's no difference.

When you call `sub.unsubscribe();` the only thing that RXJS does is to set the observers to `null`, [here you can see the original RXJS unsubscribe code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/fbcb98dd52795d94001855782d4b018a94a76084/src/internal/Subject.ts#L105):

```
  unsubscribe() {
    this.isStopped = true;
    this.closed = true;
    this.observers = null!;
  }
```

The flags are used only for further validations.

However i would recommend you to stick with the `unsubscribe` way, that would be because *you never know* what [RXJS](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs) will add in future releases. For example there's the possibility that they add a new feature, something like this:

```
  unsubscribe() {
    this.isStopped = true;
    this.closed = true;
    this.observers = null!;
    if (this.coolNewFeature) {
        this.coolNewFeature.unsubscribe()
    }
  }
```

In that scenario you'r approach of just doing `subject = null;` will cause memory-leaks (because the `coolNewFeature` might have a reference somewhere else).

Comment: @DJClayworth, truth... I removed the Angular reference and added RXJS, I hope the link references were helpful for you ;)