# Stop a pipe in the middle

Tags: angular, rxjs, refresh-token

In my angular app, I have a token refresh interceptor which intercepts 401-Unauthorized errors, attempts to refresh an access token, and perform the original http request again.

The token refresh endpoint may also fail in some cases, and return a known error (in my case it's a 400  invalid_grant error).

The part of the interceptor that refreshes the token:

```
 return this.httpClient
  .request('POST', "token", { observe: 'response' })
  .pipe(
    map(response => {
      // some logic when the token was refreshed successfully
    }),
    catchError(err => {
      this.routingService.navigateToLoginNoQuery();
      return throwError(err); // a 400 - invalid_grant error
    })
  );
```

When this happens, it gets to a catchError operator, that does 2 things: logout (with redirection to the login page), and returns throwError(error), this error it throws is the 400-Invalid_grant error.

This causes the new error to arrive to some catchError operators in the functions that originally triggered the refresh token.

Just for context:
I log the errors in the catch blocks, and I want to avoid logging these kind of errors, because they usually only mean that the user's token is expired.

What I would like to do is to somehow stop this operators chain, and just redirect to the login page.

Is that possible to stop a pipe in the middle, and avoid both getting to an outer catchError and to the next operator in the pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return an empty `Observable` to prevent events or errors from reaching a component that is going to be destroyed:

```
return this.httpClient
  .request('POST', "token", { observe: 'response' })
  .pipe(
    map(response => {
      // some logic when the token was refreshed successfully
    }),
    catchError(err => {
      this.routingService.navigateToLoginNoQuery();
      return EMPTY;
    })
  );
```

Comment: But i am not sure what will happen if the observable is inside a root-injected service which won't be destroyed. I mean, the EMPTY will cause that observable to never complete? Can it cause a memory leak?

Comment: I've written something about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59653696/do-i-need-to-unsubscribe-from-an-observable-if-the-observable-is-finished-with In short, there is a risk indeed, so you need to make sure that you unsubscribe at the right moment.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the question correclt, then maybe a [*takeUntil*](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil) operator can help you.
Example will look smth like this:

```
export class MyHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  anyError = new Subject();

  intercept(req: HttpRequest, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req)
      .pipe(
         takeUntil(this.anyError),
         catchError(err => {
             this.anyError.next();
             ...
         }
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't try this (because returning EMPTY worked for me), but not sure if it will help my situation..