# Do I need to unsubscribe if subject and observer are in the same instance?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, memory-leaks

Imagine a simple use case where :

```
class Foo {

    valueChange$: Subject<any>;

    constructor() {
        this.valueChange$ = new Subject();
        this.valueChange$.subscribe((value) => {
            //do something
        });
    }
```

(the valueChange$ subject is fired by some other class)

Do I need to to unsubscribe to `valueChange$` subject if that instance is destroyed (which I dont how to proceed), or as it's in the same class, all will be destroyed at the same time?

PS : it s quiet close that question [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59653696/do-i-need-to-unsubscribe-from-an-observable-if-the-observable-is-finished-with) but not exactly as we are in the same instance and that it s not so easy here to unsubscribe